# Adding time stamp to gradle test output

Tags: testing, gradle

We use function tests in a java project that we run with junit and gradle. They take some time. Several minutes per test and we have 200. The test output looks something like this:

```
TEST testname1(location) PASSED/FAILED
TEST testname2(location) PASSED/FAILED
```

So when we look at the log we don't know if it was test1 or test2 that took time. Is it possible to add a timestamp to the gradle output?

```
datetime: TEST testname1(location) PASSED/FAILED
datetime: TEST testname2(location) PASSED/FAILED
```

And also is it possible to write testname before we know if the test passes or failes? So if a test hangs we will see which test that is hanging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new [test logging](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/whats_new_in_gradle_1_1_test_logging) feature in Gradle 1.1 will help you with this. You can already try 1.1-rc-2 today.

The other options is to implement and register a custom `org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestListener`. See the [java/testListener](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/java/testListener/build.gradle) sample in the full Gradle distribution.